# "Bundler:GemNotFound" error in Autotest re: Thor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler, autotest, thor, ruby-2.0

**EDIT**: I rolled back to Thor 0.17.0 and that seemed to work.  Not sure why, but there it is.

I can figure out what caused this, but my autotest stopped running tests and gave me the following error:

```
"/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby" -rrubygems -S "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/exe/rspec" --tty "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/controllers/student_groups_controller_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/controllers/students_controller_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/models/student_group_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/models/student_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/models/user_spec.rb" "/Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find thor-0.18.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/charliekim/programming/Ganesh/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I've seen some similar problems on SO regarding GemNotFound errors, but the solutions don't seem to work for this.  When I run `bundle exex gem list` Thor 0.18.0 is present.

Comment: Have you set the version of Thor in your gemspec to 0.18.0?

Comment: first, what did you do to get my code looking nice?  sorry it was so ugly...  
and about the gemspec...not sure how to edit that.  I added it to my gemfile explicity, but that didn't change anything.  I'm also still learning, so it's possible I'm just confused by what you mean.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for code formatting. I am also learning. Could you please include the gemfile in your question?

Comment: yup, here it is: http://txtup.co/QDs5J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to roll back to `Thor 0.17.0`

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem when running a rake task, and done the following to fix the issue.

In your gemfile change the source from https to http://rubygems.org, and run bundle install.

My rake task then worked, not entirely sure why this occurred as im pretty sure both my dev machines are setup identically.